# c++ нужен ли деструктор для данного класса?

Tags: c++

нужен ли деструктор для класса с такими полями. если да, то как должен выглядеть

```
class fraction
{
private:
    int* a;
    int* b;
........
}
```

Comment: Если класс отвечает за владение, то да, деструктор нужен. А скорее всего, он владеет памятью, на которую указывают указатели.

Comment: Вообще, почему вдруг в классе "дробь" указатели? Почему не `int a, b;`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, задание преподавателя) не всегда рационально)

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае это нельзя определить автоматически, а то компилятор бы сам все мог сгенерировать. (Все, что он делает автоматически - это вызывает в деструкторе деструкторы полей, независимо от того, написан деструктор руками или сгенерирован.)

Существует [правило трех](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): если у вас есть копирующий конструктор, копирующее присваивание или деструктор, то скорее всего нужны они все. В С++11 сюда ещё добавляются перемещающие операции.